# How to get the height of ListView.builder() widgets to be the height of the entire stack?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a ListView.builder() inside a column, and I would like to tell the LisView.builder to set the height according to the height of the widget that it will be returning from the builder method. How do I do that?

Comment: Take a look at `PageView`. I think you want to achieve something similar. [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html)

Comment: I ain't working on a page by page basis. Just a simple listview that can be scrolled horizontally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `ListView` in a `SizedBox` with some fixed height. Setting to children height is impractical since Flutter would have to check the size of every element in the list and calculate the maximum.

Comment: I really wanted to avoid hardcoded values but that seems to be the only possible solution in this case

Comment: If you want something more dynamic you can wrap Column in [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) and calculate SizedBox height based on Column height and width or both.

Comment: But `Expanded` would probably the recommended approach in that case.

Comment: Can you give a mock example? Just to get how it works

Comment: All I am saying it doesn't have to be a hardcoded value. If you want to specify the height of your ListView relative to parent container size, you can wrap parent container in LayoutBuilder and pass something like `height: constraints.maxHeight / 3` to SizedBox. This way your ListView will be 3rd of the Column height.

But it all depends on what are the contents of the column and what visual result do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but looking at your question it looks like you want to render listview within the sizes which child widgets are taking
For that we can assign `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min`, to column and `shrinkWrap: true` to Listview.builder

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<String> itemsList = [
    "item0",
    "item1",
    "item2",
    "item3",
    "item4",
    "item5"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ListView Sample"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.black54,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: itemsList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                      child:
                      Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child:Text(
                          itemsList[index],
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),),
                      width: 100,
                      height: 20,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                      color: Colors.red);
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use global key to get height of list view or column,

But the height can be fetched only after a build is completed

```dart
    //user gloabl key to get height of list view or column
    GlobalKey key = GlobalKey();
     
    SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          key: key,
          children: [...]
       )
       
       //here you can get widget height
           double totalWidgetHeight = key.currentContext!.size!.height;
```